# Integrated Address generation gives 16 bit randomly generated payment ID

Tags: payment-id, integrated-address, transfer

Using **[integrated address](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#make_integrated_address)** method without any argument while calling, it gives me response of 16 bit longer string of payment ID covered with **<>**.

According to documentation of wallet RPC for **[transfer](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer)** method it requires 64 characters hex string to pass in Payment ID.

I have 16 character string and I want 64 character strings, in this case what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, integrated addresses embed an **8 byte** (64 bit, 16 hex chars), payment ID. Monero started with an older format of payment ID which allowed for 32 bytes, but this was deprecated in favor of shorter 8 byte encrypted payment IDs, as used by integrated addresses.

Second, when using the RPC method [transfer](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer), if you are transferring to an integrated address, you would not supply the *optional* parameter `payment_id` as this is already set in the integrated address.

> I have 16 character string and I want 64 character strings, in this case what should I do?

I strongly recommend against this. Payment IDs in general are being deprecated in favor of subaddresses. If you *must* use a payment ID right now, use the short payment IDs (e.g. the type embedded in integrated addresses), therefore limited to 8 bytes. There really is no good reason for any new implementations to use payment IDs.

Comment: Thank you for simple explanation about payment ID, is integrated address is deprecated in current implementation of wallet_RPC method?

Comment: "is integrated address is deprecated in current implementation of wallet_RPC method?" <- you can still use integrated addresses at the moment, but advice is to use subaddresses instead.